# CakePHP having trouble saving data (HABTM)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to create wish lists.

There are user and product models. A user has a wish list. A wish list has many products.

The reason I am making it user has wishlist and wishlist has products is so I can have a url like wish_lists/add/:product_id

---

I created a table called `wish_lists` with `id`, `user_id`, and `name`.

I also created a table called `products_wish_lists` with `wish_list_id` and `product_id`.

I made here is the wishlists controller:

```
class WishListsController extends AppController 
{
    var $hasOne = 'User';
    var $hasMany = 'Product';

    function beforeFilter() 
    {        
        parent::beforeFilter();       
        $this->Auth->deny('add');    
    }

    function add($id)
    {
        $user =  $this->Session->read("Auth.User");

        $this->WishList->set(array(
            'User.id' => $user['id'],
            'Product.id'=>$id,
            'WishList.name'=>'default'
        ));

        if($this->WishList->save())
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('This product has been added to your wishlist.', 'flash_good');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Error: This product was not added to your wishlist.', 'flash_bad');   
        }

        $this->redirect(array("controller"=>"products","action"=>"view",$id));
    }
}
```

When I go to `localhost/wish_lists/add/1` It tells me everytime that it saved. but no data is being added to the database.

Not sure what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never do it that way, I always build a `$data` array to pass as parameter one to the save function.

I'm not sure, therefore, whether that syntax will allow you to specify the model as you have done, i.e. `'Model.field'`. In any case, `$this->WishList->save()` will only save the Wishlist part.

Better, in my opinion, would be:

```
$saveData = array(
    'User'=>array('id'=>$user['id']),
    'Product'=>array('id'=>$id),
    'WishList'=>array('name'=>'default'));
$this->WishList->saveAll($saveData);
```

(or something like that, I've been programming ColdFusion for the last three months and my PHP can be a bit addled)

Answer (score 0):

you are setting the array wrong. it should be $data['User']['id'] = 123; $data['Product']['id'] = 321;

$this->Wishlist->saveAll($data);

There is no point saving the name as that can be found from the product table.

you can have a look at the code here for more ideas https://github.com/Infinitas-Plugins/shop

there is a generic component method in the following link that saves products to the cart or wishlist (different db's) as its pretty much the same thing.

https://github.com/Infinitas-Plugins/shop/blob/master/controllers/components/shop.php#L62